# Angular Reative Forms > User customized forms error

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to implement a feature on my angular app where the users will be able to create their own forms (selecting fields/validation/etc). Once they create the form, I'll store it's JSON structure on the DB for use later:

```
export interface FormModel {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  type: 'group' | 'control';
  children: FormModel[];
  isArray: boolean;
}
```

A sample structure is this:

```
[{
    id: 'users',
    name: 'Users',
    type: 'group',
    isArray: true,
    children: [
      {
        id: "user",
        name: "User",
        type: 'group',
        isArray: false,
        children: [
          {
            id: "name",
            name: "Name",
            type: 'control',
            children: null,
            isArray: false
          },
          {
            id: "age",
            name: "Age",
            type: 'control',
            children: null,
            isArray: false
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: "user",
        name: "User",
        type: 'group',
        isArray: false,
        children: [
          {
            id: "name",
            name: "Name",
            type: 'control',
            children: null,
            isArray: false,
          },
          {
            id: "age",
            name: "Age",
            type: 'control',
            children: null,
            isArray: false
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }, {
    id: 'comments',
    name: 'Comments',
    type: 'control',
    children: null,
    isArray: false
  }
  ];
```

After creating the reactive form based on the JSON loaded from the DB, I'm having difficulties creating the respective html since it has recursion.

After many attempts, I managed to get to the following, where it generates a HTML similar to what I understand should be needed:

```
<div formGroupName="users">
  <div formArrayName="0">
    <div formGroupName="user">
      <input type="text" formControlName="name">
      <input type="text" formControlName="age">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div formArrayName="0">
    <div formGroupName="user">
      <input type="text" formControlName="name">
      <input type="text" formControlName="age">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The template I've used is the following:

```
<form name="myForm" [formGroup]="myForm" fxLayout="column" fxFlex>
    <div formGroupName="variables">

        <ng-template #recursiveList let-controls let-prefix="prefix">
            <ng-container *ngFor="let item of controls; let i = index;">

                <input type="text" [formControlName]="item.id" *ngIf="(item?.children?.length > 0) == false">

            <div *ngIf="item?.children?.length > 0 && item.isArray" [formArrayName]="item.id">
                <ng-container
                    *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveArray; context:{ $implicit: item.children, prefix: item.isArray }">
                </ng-container>
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="item?.children?.length > 0 && !item.isArray" [formGroupName]="item.id">
                <ng-container
                    *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveList; context:{ $implicit: item.children, prefix: item.isArray }">
                </ng-container>
            </div>
        </ng-container>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveList; context:{ $implicit: formFields, prefix: '' }">
    </ng-container>

    <ng-template #recursiveArray let-controls let-prefix="prefix">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let item of controls; let i = index;">

            <div [formGroupName]="i">

                <input type="text" [formControlName]="item.id" *ngIf="(item?.children?.length > 0) == false">

                <div *ngIf="item?.children?.length > 0 && item.isArray" [formArrayName]="item.id">
                    <ng-container
                        *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveArray; context:{ $implicit: item.children, prefix: item.isArray }">
                    </ng-container>
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="item?.children?.length > 0 && !item.isArray" [formGroupName]="item.id">
                    <ng-container
                        *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveList; context:{ $implicit: item.children, prefix: item.isArray }">
                    </ng-container>
                </div>
            </div>

        </ng-container>
    </ng-template>
  </div>

</form>
```

It seems to me that it is right, but I keep getting errors:

```
ERROR
Error: Cannot find control with path: 'variables -> 0'
ERROR
Error: Cannot find control with path: 'variables -> 0 -> user'
```

I have created a stackblitz with the sample:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mtbien

Could you guys help me identify the problem? I've been working on this for 2 days without any success :(

Thanks!

Comment: Your generated html needs to be in a different order for a FormArray. You need to assign to the outer html element the ```formArrayName="users"``` and inside you need the ```[formGroupName]="i"``` where ```i``` is the current index of the FormControl or FormGroup inside your array. Maybe this helps: https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-formarray-dynamic-fields/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ersenkoening say, for work with FormsGroup and Form Arrays you can use the "controls", directly. Use FormArrayName, Form Group, etc, can be a real headache.

See that the form-array.component.html of Ersenkoening can be coded more simple like

```
<div [formGroup]="formArray">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let child of formArray.controls; let i = index">
        <app-form-group [formGroup]="child"></app-form-group>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

Yes is a different way to mannage a FormArray but remember that a formArray it's only a "especial" FormGroup.

**Update**
With this idea, we are going to go more deeper, in the html only use [formControl], so, we need pass the "control" as a variable. See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mtbien-orpv9e?file=app%2Fform-field-overview-example.html)

The form-filed-view is like

```
<form name="myForm" [formGroup]="myForm" fxLayout="column" fxFlex>
    <div *ngFor="let item of formFields;let i=index">
        {{item.id}}
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveList; context:{ 
            $implicit: formFields[i], 
            <!--see how pass the control of myForm--->
            control:myForm.get(item.id) }">
        </ng-container>
    </div>

    <ng-template #recursiveList let-item let-control="control">
        <div *ngIf="!item.children">
            {{item.id}}<input [formControl]="control">
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="item.children">
      <div *ngIf="!item.isArray">
        <div *ngFor="let children of item.children">
            <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveList; context:{
                 $implicit:children, 
                 <!--see how pass the control of a formGroup--->
                 control:control.get(children.id)}">
            </ng-container>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="item.isArray">
        <div *ngFor="let children of item.children;let i=index">
            <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveList; context:{ 
                  $implicit:children, 
                 <!--see how pass the control of a formArray--->
                  control:control.at(i)}">
            </ng-container>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </ng-template>
</form>
<pre>
{{myForm?.value|json}}
</pre>
```

**Update 2** simplify the creation of the form, see [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mtbien-wnvqtw?file=app%2Fform-field-overview-example.ts)

```
  ngOnInit() {
    let group = new FormGroup({});
    this.formFields.forEach(element => {
      let formItem = this.createFormGroup(element);
      group.addControl(element.id, formItem);
    });

    this.myForm = group;
  }

  private createFormGroup(formItem: FormModel) {

    if (formItem.type=="group")
    {
      if (formItem.isArray && formItem.children.length<formItem.minQtd)
      {
        const add={...formItem.children[0]}
        //here we can "clean" the value
        while (formItem.children.length<formItem.minQtd)
        formItem.children.push(add)
      }
      let group:FormGroup=new FormGroup({});
      let controls:any[]=[]
      formItem.children.forEach(element=>{
        let item=this.createFormGroup(element);
        if (formItem.isArray)
           controls.push(item);
        else
          group.addControl(element.id, item);
      })
      if (!formItem.isArray)
        return group;

      return new FormArray(controls)
    } 
    if (formItem.type=="control")
      return new FormControl();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, it really helped me!

Comment: I really liked your approach. After further developing on it I realised that the use I was giving for isArray was incorrect. I don't want to have to repeat it on de FormModel obj, I just need a quantity property. I tried applying it without success. Could you check the forked version of your stackblitz and see what I'm doing wrong? Thanks https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mtbien-dxagtc

Comment: @HobojoeBr, you has a problem when generate the form. I've updated my answer adding a new function to create the form. Sinceraly I'm so lazy to try to fight with your variable firstLevel. To take acount the "minQtd" variable simply push as children so many items to reach this value. Ah!, in the form, the iterate is over item.children, you needn't use getForItems and two concatenate loops

Comment: In https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mtbien-4kra4k?file=app%2Fform-field-overview-example.html you has an aproach to show the form using tables to display the formArray. I add a optionals properties: "isArray", "groupName" and "keys" that can help you

Comment: Thanks! it really helped me!

Answer (score 1):

Your generated html needs to be in a different order for a FormArray. You need to assign the `formArrayName="users"` to the outer html element and inside that html element you need the `[formGroupName]="i"` where `i` is the current index of the FormControl or FormGroup inside your array.

So you are looking for a structure like this:

```
<div formArrayName="FORM_ARRAY_NAME"
  *ngFor="let item of orderForm.get('items').controls; let i = index;">
  <div [formGroupName]="i">
    <input formControlName="FORM_CONTROL_NAME">
  </div>

  Chosen name: {{ orderForm.controls.items.controls[i].controls.name.value }}
</div>
```

[Here](https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-formarray-dynamic-fields/) is a nice article describing the right setup for a FormArray.

---

Having said that, I forked your stackblitz and had a look. I moved the FormArray and FormGroups into separate components instead of using ng-template, but if you really need to, you could do the same using ng-template.

So basically what I changed was the order and bindings for a FormArray and I worked with the FormGroup, FormArrays and FormControls objects itself rather than using the FormGroup/FormControl values like isFormArray inside the template to determine which template needs to be used.

A possible solution for your problem could look like this:

**Starting component**

```
<form name="myForm" [formGroup]="myForm" fxLayout="column" fxFlex>
  <app-form-group [formGroup]="myForm.get('variables')"></app-form-group>
</form>
```

**form-group.component.ts**

```
<div [formGroup]="formGroup"> // necessary because the <form> tag is outside this component
  <ng-container *ngFor="let key of controlKeys">
    <ng-container *ngIf="!isFormArray(key) && !isFormGroup(key)">
      <p>
        <label>{{key}}</label>
        <input type="text" [formControlName]="key">
      </p>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngIf="isFormArray(key)">
      <app-form-array [formArray]="formGroup.get(key)" [formArrayName]="key" [parentFormGroup]="formGroup" ></app-form-array>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngIf="isFormGroup(key)">
      <app-form-group [formGroup]="formGroup.get(key)"></app-form-group>
    </ng-container>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

**form-froup.component.ts**

```
  public isFormArray(key: string): boolean {
    return this.formGroup.get(key) instanceof FormArray
  }

  public isFormGroup(key: string): boolean {
    return this.formGroup.get(key) instanceof FormGroup
  }

  get controlKeys() {
    return Object.keys(this.formGroup.controls);
  }
```

**form-array.component.html**

```
 <div [formGroup]="parentFormGroup">
  <div [formArrayName]="formArrayName">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let child of formArray.controls; let i = index">
      <div [formGroupName]="i">
        <app-form-group [formGroup]="child"></app-form-group>
      </div>
    </ng-container>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Here is the forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mtbien-tju9yw)

**Note**

If you split up the the form elements inside a `<form>` into different subcomponents, you need a FormGroup-Binding on any element e.g. simply a `<div>`

This implementation expects that all FormArray items are FormGroups. If that's not always the case you would need to add that.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I got it working. It is very helpful! I wish I could accept both answers, I'm only accepting Eliseo's because it is simpler!